# How is it possible to make a matrix of array in R?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

What i want to have is a ***matrix*** in which each element is an ***array*** itself.
This array is taken subsetting a dataframe, but the example can be generalized for any array.

I tried with:

```
My_matrix <- matrix(array(), nrow = NROW, ncol =  NCOL) 

for (i in 1:NROW){
  for(j in 1:NCOL){
    My_matrix[i,j] <- df[df$var1 == j & df$var2== i,]$var3
  }
}
```

but I got this message error:

```
Error in My_matrix[i,j] <- df[df$var1== j & df$var2== i,]$var3 : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

How should I define and access each element of the matrix and each element of the contained array?

Comment: While this sounds like *inception* of matrices, can't you just make an *n*-dim array? For example, if each "cell" of a 2x3 matrix is a 4x5 matrix, then `ary <- array(dim=c(2,3,4,5))`, and `ary[1,2,,]` gives you the 4x5 matrix within cell `[1,2]`.

Comment: It would help do know how `df` looks like, can you provide representative data? One that works really well is `dput(head(df))`, where it gives an unambiguous look at the data structure. Thanks.

Comment: While this is technically feasible, what is your rationale for structuring it this way? For instance, given your code, it seems straight-forward to index your nested-matrix with `i` and `j`, but ... you can also just subset the frame as well. Are you dealing with such a large (and perfectly structured) frame such that you see performance issues when indexing? If so, have you tried `data.table` with keys set to the first two columns? Its performance is significantly faster (especially with keys) than `data.frame`.

Comment: One more by-the-way (unless/until you respond :-), realize that by using a `matrix` (and `array`), you don't have the liberty of embedding a `data.frame` in it. `matrix` is just a special case of `array` (where there are two dimensions), and anything in a `matrix`/`array` must be the same simple/scalar class (i.e., `numeric`, `character`, ... not `data.frame`). You would need to adapt your current code to wrap `as.matrix(...)` around your `df[...,]`.

Comment: `df` has 3 variables.
var1 ranges from 1 to 45, var2 ranges from 1 to 3 and they both are a characteristic of a time that is var3.

I would like to create a 45 x 3 matrix where each element is an array.
For example, `My_matrix[10,2]` should contain an array of times (var3) obtained subsetting `df` with `var1 = 10` and `var2 = 2`.
I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: So the fact is that I don't know a priori the size of my array

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand that: (1) the base array is 45x3; (2) each cell has a differently sized matrix; and (3) this is not known apriori. Gotcha. *Not possible.* An array (matrix) is always perfectly dimensioned, and while you can dynamically change one or more of the dimensions, you change for all cells.

Alternative: *list-columns*.

```r
dat <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=11:13)
dat$z <- lapply(3:5, function(i) matrix(seq_len(i^2), nr=i))
dat
#   x  y
# 1 1 11
# 2 2 12
# 3 3 13
#                                                                                           z
# 1                                                                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
# 2                                     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
# 3 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
```

That doesn't look very appealing, but if you want a different *presentation*, you might consider assigning it as a `tibble::tbl_df` (available whenever `dplyr` is loaded as well). (Note that *presentation* is distinct from *storage* and *accessibility*.)

```r
library(tibble)
as_tibble(dat)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#       x     y z                
#   <int> <int> <list>           
# 1     1    11 <int[,3] [3 x 3]>
# 2     2    12 <int[,4] [4 x 4]>
# 3     3    13 <int[,5] [5 x 5]>
```

Subsetting is consistent:

```r
dat$z[ dat$x == 2 & dat$y == 12 ]
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13
# [2,]    2    6   10   14
# [3,]    3    7   11   15
# [4,]    4    8   12   16

### note that you need an extra [[1]] to get to the real data
m <- dat$z[ dat$x == 2 & dat$y == 12 ][[1]]
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13
# [2,]    2    6   10   14
# [3,]    3    7   11   15
# [4,]    4    8   12   16
m[3,4]
# [1] 15
```

Comment: Thank you r2evans, this is very near to what I expected! Actually, I would prefer that `m` was a simply array `1xN` , how this would be possible?

Comment: How do you define it? I came up with a completely-contrived set of matrices for each element. You could have done `dat$z <- list(NA, NULL, matrix(NA, nrow=5000, ncol=1e5))` and it would have worked. The "power" of the list-column is that each cell can be whatever you want it to be. So if you want the second cell of `z` to be `array(NA, dim=c(1,N))` (or equivalently `matrix(NA, nc=5)`) then that's how you should instantiate it.

Comment: Emanuele, what you have come up with? Does this answer work for you? If not, you are unlikely to get anything else unless you [edit] your question and provide more information. I know that you think the first two dims might be 45x3, are all submatrices exactly the same size as the others? What are the dims of the submatrices?

Comment: Hi r2evans, I found your answer precious and useful but in the end I decided to switch to Matlab where I could end the task easily. Thank you.